# NET MVC RegisterRoutes rule

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
        routes.MapRoute(
         "Default",
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
         new string[] { "Teng.Web.Controllers" });


        routes.MapRoute(
            "CMSArticle",
             "{Classify}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { Classify = @"", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "Teng.Web.Controllers" });
```

To match CMSArticle  http://localhost:4848/ss/home/index/5

I want to http://localhost:4848/ss/home/index 
go CMSArticle  Routes

Comment: if  http://localhost:4848/home/index/5  go to Default Routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is classify an actual parameter?  I believe they need to be in order of importance.  If the route doesn't match to one it falls to the next.  Try the below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "CMSArticle",
                 "ss/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "Teng.Web.Controllers" });

routes.MapRoute(
             "Default",
              "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new string[] { "Teng.Web.Controllers" });
```

You can also set specific controller/action in the route so that it doens't work for all controllers and/or actions.

Comment: He should not not be found Default
CMSArticle go inside to find it? Because ss is not fixed

Comment: If it is not fixed then why not just add another controller? SSController perhaps and use the default routing. localhost:4848/ss/Index/{id} or simply localhost:4848/ss/{id}

Answer (score 1):

home and ss both seems controller names. you have to go for default routes. but before that check your Url.

- http://localhost:4848/ss/home/index/5 - Check the ss. normall it comes as
  **http://localhost:4848/home/index/5**